# I wanted to parse the data with the same label ID (column A & B) the difference is that column in excel csv file then parse column C,D

Tags: excel, csv, perl, parsing

I have excel csv file to parse with 2 columns A & B, my objective is if the column A & B condition will meet then it will parse the column C & D. Please help me code this in perl. Kindly see the sample data to parse.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "parse"? Do you mean extract the data? Is the file a CSV file (i.e. plain text file) or an `.xlsx` file?

Comment: yes to extract the  data . it's a CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that prints the lines which have col0 == col1:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

my $fn = 'file.csv';
open ( my $fh, '<', $fn ) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";
while( my $line = <$fh> ) {
    chomp $line;
    my @arr = split /,/, $line;
    next if @arr < 2;
    next if $arr[0] !~ /^\d+$/;
    next if $arr[1] !~ /^\d+$/;
    say join ',', @arr if $arr[0] == $arr[1];
}
close $fh;
```

Comment: i wanted to learn the hash version on how to extract the data result if column A + B is true then print column C & D an so on if there's any more columns.

Comment: @kayegabato What do you mean by *"A + B is true"*? Can you give some examples?

Comment: i am referring to my sample csv file, if you see column A  & B is true then will print column C&D. based on my data if you can see column A is 1 and column B is 1 then will 5.6 & 63 will be printed and the rest of the rows til the end.

Comment: So the condition is true if not both A and B are zero? Like A=2 and B=10 is true, but A=0 and B=0 is false?

Comment: based on column A & B  it needs be true same as the same data, then will print the result which is column C & D. when its false i don't need to display anything since its wrong. I more concern if the column A & B are true then print the result column C &D

Comment: *" it needs be true same as the same data"* what does that mean? What is the data? Do you mean column C and D?

Comment: please see the sample data https://i.stack.imgur.com/irFRB.png

Comment: sorry that picture does not clarify, I think. (By the way it is the same image as in your question right?) The image just says *"if ID=1 and ID=1 then will parse column C & D"*